# How to set different xlink:href in svg pattern on each use

Tags: image, svg, href

I have an svg hexagon duplicated seven times in an array, with each hexagon filled with an image from a pattern, like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="390" width="375">
  <defs>
    <polygon id="hex" points="150,65 112.5,130 37.5,130 0,65 37.5,0 112.5,0" fill="url('#image-bg')" />
     <pattern id="image-bg" x="0" y="0" height="150" width="150" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <image width="150" height="150" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/150/150"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="112.5" y="0"><title>Cat 1</title></use>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="0" y="65"><title>Cat 2</title></use>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="225" y="65"><title>Cat 3</title></use>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="112.5" y="130"><title>Cat 4</title></use>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="0" y="195"><title>Cat 5</title></use>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="225" y="195"><title>Cat 6</title></use>
  <use xlink:href="#hex" x="112.5" y="260"><title>Cat 7</title></use>
</svg>
```

can I set an attribute or something in the `use` tag (or set a tag nested within the use tag) so that I can specify a different image for each hexagon? Or do I have to repeat the whole `<pattern ...>` tag for each image?

Comment: No, you are using use inappropriately if you need to do that. Just just different polygons. I.e. repeat the pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to avoid repetition of the height, width, and patternUnits part of the svg, since these will be the same for all images. It seemed neater to be able to substitute in a different value for the `xlink:href` part only, since I'll have hundreds of these, eventually

Comment: You can have a template pattern that will save some typing by using the pattern element's xlink:href capability to point to an empty pattern template.